# Методы для ajax запросов

Tags: php, ajax

Есть методы которые буду выполнять аякс запросом.Вопрос такой,как правильно закрывать доступ для такиех методов если к ним обращаются напрямую не через аякс? Пока конечно просто проверку делаю какого типа запрос,но хотелось бы услышать как правильно закрывать доступ таким методам.

```
public function remove_holiday(){
        if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()){
            echo 'Not ajax request';
        }else{
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $result = $this->my_model->delete('holidays', array('id' => $id));

            if($result){
                echo json_encode(true);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если по простому то все правильно, вначале метода проверяешь, всю логику оборачиваешь проверкой к примеру как в Yii.
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) { Твоя логика }.
Если ты не используешь фреймворк, то можешь проверять так :
/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* special ajax here */
    die($content);
}